# Evaluating $\int \frac{x^a}{(bx-1)^2} dx$ through hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

How may one integrate the function

$\frac{x^a}{(bx-1)^2}$ with respect to x?

I have attempted to evaluate the function with Mathematica and it gives the solution in the form of:

$\frac{x^{a+1}._2F_1(1, 2; 2-a; \frac{1}{1-bx})}{(a-1)(bx-1)^2}$

But I have no idea what substitutions have to be made for one to obtain the above solution.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is this an indefinite integral? Because if it is a definite integral (with the appropriate limits) then this can potentially be rewritten as a Beta function which has a known value for the definite integral. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible evaluation of that integral. For $|bx|<1$
\begin{align*}\int \frac{x^a}{(bx-1)^2} dx&=\int x^a\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(bx)^{k-1} dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kb^{k-1}\int x^{a+k-1}\,dx
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kb^{k-1} x^{a+k}}{a+k}+c\\
&=x^{a+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k(bx)^{k-1}}{a+k}+c
=x^{a+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(bx)^{k-1}-\frac{ax^{a}}{b}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(bx)^{k}}{a+k}+c\\
&=\frac{x^{a+1}}{1-bx}-\frac{ax^{a}}{b}\Phi(bx,1,a)+\frac{x^{a}}{b}+c\\
&=\frac{x^{a}}{b(1-bx)}-\frac{ax^{a}}{b}\Phi(bx,1,a)+c
\end{align*}
where $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).